# How to query between a series of dates per year?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the tables `resumes` and `experiences` in a one to many relationship with the following structure

```
resumes

  id int
  title varchar(255)

experiencies

  id int
  resume_id int
  from_date datetime
  to_date datetime
```

I try to get all resumes where a parameter year is between the values ​​of the fields `from_date` and `to_date` in experiences table

I attach a sqlfidlle with the structure

For example, given the following data

Table resumes
[image]

Table experiencies
[image]

If the parameter is `2010` the results I expect are the resume with id 1 and 2

1 because the experience in row 1 is in 2010 this despite the fact that the other experiences associated with the resume 1 are not in the year 2010. And 2 because 2010 is between 2008 and 2018

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can we see your attempt?

Comment: Right now I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Year` function to get year from date columns and apply the where clause like below -

```
select * 
from experiencies 
where year(from_date) <= 2010 and year(to_date) >= 2010
```

You may use `BETWEEN` in where clause too.

```
SET @Param = 2010
select * 
from experiencies 
where @Param between year(from_date) and year(to_date)
```

Comment: @Strawberry it's supposed to be column name with underscore, updated. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering, the solution turns out to be simple. thanks, again